# Delivery to Ontario, Canada

Tags: email

I need delivery to Toronto, ON, Canada.
Who do I email? And how do I ask for it?
How will I know that they received my email? Please help! I've already ordered and made payment!

Comment: What is it that you ordered?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for a delivery of an Ubuntu Live CD that you ordered?  Where did you come from (link/URL) that you were trying to order something through?

This is typically a forum/QA site specifically for issue/questions about using Ubuntu OS... not really as much about Canonical (Ubuntu designer/devs) support.

I think you want to go here, whatever your specific question might be:

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us

Cheers!  :)